# How to use system environment variables in angular

Tags: angular, environment-variables

I've been using spring boot which has a nice feature of using the system environment variables in properties file, now I want to use the system environment variable to set the backend server url in angular. I'm not sure how this works in angular.

For eg. BACKEND_URL=http://somerandomurl

I don't want to hardcode the server url in config file. I want to do something like apiurl=$(BACKEND_URL)

This is due to fact that I'll be using kubernetes while deployment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can use Angular environment.ts file to configure your backend URLs.

### In fact you can assign multiple backend url as you wish. For example (prod, dev, qa)

```
 // environment.ts
    export const environment = {
      production: false,
      baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3333'
    };
    
 // environment.prod.ts
    export const environment = {
      production: true,  
      baseUrl: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'
    };

 // environment.qa.ts
    export const environment = {
      production: true,  
      baseUrl: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'
    };
```

Then you can build the angular project with relevent environment you prefer. Angular will assign the base urls acccording to the passed parameter in build time.

```
ng build --configuration=prod
ng build --configuration=qa
```

From herewith Im attaching reference link of official angular documentation on how to do it [here](https://angular.io/guide/build).

> Also please find the practical demonstration here. Please refer to the
> stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/specific-data-services-swqehm-sx57vc?file=src/app/utils/http/data.service.ts) and it relevent article [here](https://indepth.dev/how-to-use-the-environment-for-specific-http-services).

Comment: What if I don't know the url before deploying the application? Like I don't want to hardcode the url into the config file

Comment: Then u need to get the url from an api and set it in your store or localStorage and use it all across your application @VivekGupta

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to the OP, since you DO need to hardcode the values into the environment file (one or the other), but I suppose this solution is what's possible in Angular.